# Write a cron expression in docker-compose.yml environment

Tags: java, docker-compose, cron, java-opts

I am struggling to put cron expression 0 */1 * ? * * * into docker-compose.yml as environment variable..

I tried to escape * with backslash, also " and ', but no luck.

```
cont1:
  image: some-image
  restart: unless-stopped
  volumes:
    - some_volume
  environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS=
      -Dserver.port=${DP_PORT:-8080}
      -Ddoc.office.viaFile=true
      -DdocumentCache.cleanUp.cron.timer='0 */1 * ? * * *'
```

Output from YAML parser:

```
{
  "cont1": {
    "environment": [
      "JAVA_OPTS= -Dserver.port=${DP_PORT:-8080} -Ddoc.office.viaFile=true -DdocumentCache.cleanUp.cron.timer='0 */1 * ? * * *'"
    ], 
    "image": "some-image", 
    "restart": "unless-stopped", 
    "volumes": [
      "some-image"
    ]
  }
}
```

YAML is valid..
Error by docker-compose:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class proc.1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: proc.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your YAML in an online YAML editor, like this one: https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ and see what output it produces, and whether it's an output you expect.

Comment: I tried yml validator and it is valid yml, but still docker compose has a problem with these star and space characters.

Error: Could not find or load main class proc.1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: proc.1